# Netologo Behavior Space: have each agent report values

Tags: netlogo, behavior

I'd like to run a Behavior Space sweep in my model and have each agent report the respective values that they own in the results.

Here is the code I am using to ask each agent to report values.

```
to-report wrapup 

  ask artcollectors

  [
    type who
    type " "
    type num-artcollectors
    type " "
    type num-subjectmatters
    type " "
    type c-artcollection-size
    type " "
    type c-self-reference-bias
    type " "
    type c-artdisposal-rate
    type " "
    type c-random-bias
    type " , "
    print clist
  ]
end
```

When I do this and report to the Console, Netlogo will make the first run and report results to the console, then Nelogo stops at the end of the first run and reports

```
"Reached end of reporter procedure without REPORT being called.
error while observer running END
  called by procedure WRAPUP
  called by procedure __EVALUATOR"
```

So I get that I am not running the right syntax in my wrapup procedure. Can anyone suggest the magic words I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `to-report` procedure is a reporter and must therefore return some value to the caller.  Your `wrapup` procedure is actually a command - the agent does something and then stops.  So, you should use the declaration for a command procedure, `to wrapup` rahter than `to-report wrapup`.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It does not work.  NetLogo seems to be insisting that only to-reports be used for Behavior Space.  My challenge is how to wrap this procedure into a to-report where each agent shares its values.

Comment: Where are you putting `wrapup` in behavior space?  Under "Measure runs ...", or under "Final Commands"?  The former requires a reporter, the latter simply a command.  If `wrapup` has to be a reporter, you can just put `report TRUE` before the `end` statement.  Do you want these values at the end of each run, or at the end of each iteration?  Looking further down the road, do you eventually want these values to go to a file?

Comment: Jeez!  I'm kicking myself for not thinking of inserting the procedure in Final Commands.  Ultimately, I'm looking for a printed file where each row is a single observation of one of the contents of my agent's list (i.e., artwork identifier) along with parameter variables.  To start, I'd like the values to be reported at the end of each run, not each tick.  Any pointers?

Comment: So to be clear, you want each line to show all the values for one agent, preceded by the agent's who number?  That seems to be what your `wrapup` procedure is sending to the console.  The CSV extension is great for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Exactly!  I've gone the full way asking each agent to file-type values with a file-print at the end.  My current stumbling block is that occasionally, Netlogo is ending a line prematurely and printing out the next set of values out of order on a new line.  If I can't fix this, I'll open a new issue.  Thanks so much for pointing me to using the procedure in the Final Commands and much appreciation for your role in furthering the community.